# Setting focus to a button from text box?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I have a few text boxes and buttons on my form.

Lets say txtBox1 is next to btnSubmit1,
txtBox2 is next to btnSubmit2,
txtBox3 is next to btnSubmit3.

How can I set the focus on btnSubmit3 when the user starts to type something in txtBox3.
Meaning..... if a user type in a text box the program will know what button to fire when the user press the enter key.

Comment: I am using ASP.NET 2.0 and VB.net code

Comment: You can't set focus when you start typing - otherwise you won't be able to continue typing. You need to change the default button for the page.

Comment: Of course that make sense.....but how would i do it then when all 3 of my text boxes and buttons are on 1 page? I need to know what text box to set the focus depending on where the user is on the current page.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you use a panel, you should be able to set a defaultbutton. I´m not sure if it´s an win forms application or a web forms application, but this is how you should do it with web forms:

```
<asp:Panel id="panel1" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button1">
   <asp:TextBox id="textbox1" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button id="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button 1" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel id="panel2" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button2">
   <asp:TextBox id="textbox2" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button id="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button 2" />
</asp:Panel>

<asp:Panel id="panel3" runat="server" DefaultButton="Button3">
   <asp:TextBox id="textbox3" runat="server" />
   <asp:Button id="Button3" runat="server" Text="Button 3" />
</asp:Panel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript and add a "onblur" for those TextBoxes...

Example:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="t1" runat="server" onblur="CheckIfTextBox1ShouldFocusOnButton1();" />
```

:)

Comment: MMM, what must i place inside my CheckIfTextBox1ShouldFocusOnButton1();

Answer (score 0):

I've seen it done like this but don't ask me to explain it or to say what the pros and cons are over any other method. Just thought I would publish it in case its useful to you.

```
// Fires a particular event when enter is pressed within a textbox.
function FireButtonOnEnter(controlID)
{
    if((event.which ? event.which : event.keyCode) == 13)
    {
        window.event.returnValue = false;
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
        document.getElementById(controlID).click();
    }
}
```

Call it by adding the following for the textbox...

```
txtOrgName.Attributes.Add("OnKeyDown", String.Format("return FireButtonOnEnter('{0}');", btnOrgNameGo.ID));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an easy solution if you know that the only browser being used is IE.

You just have to add to the Page load

```
txtBox1.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13)
__doPostBack('" + btnSubmit1.UniqueID + "','')");

txtBox2.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13)
__doPostBack('" + btnSubmit2.UniqueID + "','')");

txtBox3.Attributes.Add("onKeyPress", "javascript:if (event.keyCode == 13) 
__doPostBack('" + btnSubmit3.UniqueID + "','')");
```

The reason that this only works in IE is that it uses the Javascript "event" key word that doesn't work in Firefox.

Comment: Hi, this does not work.....is it the same code for the VB.NET? I know i must leave the ";" out.